What exactly is happening when I set up a percentage width on a child element inside of a flexed/fit-content parent container?
I recently ran into a scenario that made me realize I have no idea what is happening in order to output the result that is being outputted. I have the following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .parent {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: #00AA00;
    }

    .child {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #AA00AA;
    }

    img {
      width: 30%;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="imgs/morrslieb.png">
      <!-- position: absolute; elements -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

Which outputs:

I ended up in this scenario while trying to center the moon, along with other elements tied to its parent (the child div) absolutely. I needed the child div to have its width fit the content which, to my understanding, flex does by default.
After getting that result back, I tried display: inline-block and width: fit-content individually on the child div, but neither changed anything. It wasn't until I changed the img width to be a rigid value (300px) that it suddenly resolved itself.
I realized that I accidentally set up the img's width to be based off of its parent's width which would be determined by the img's width and so on and so forth...
My question after all this is Why is this the result that is outputted?
I would have thought it would create two elements with the width of 0 or something.
Are there fallback values that the child div's width was set to?

the browser will first ignore the percentage width to define the parent width and then it will use the defined width as a reference for the percentage calculation
